# Reduce width of rmarkdown doc

Tags: r-markdown

I'm trying to reduce the width of my rmarkdown HTML output, so that it looks better on the page. I have tried pretty much every option online, including defining the 'width' parameter, styling it using;

```
<style type="text/css">
.main-container {
  max-width: 1800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
</style>
```

Here is my code:

```
---
title: "Project"
author: "Name"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    theme: lumen 
    highlight: textmate
    # df_print: paged
    code_folding: hide
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: inline
  markdown: 
    wrap: 72
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
---
```

I'm wondering if this is even possible (to force a smaller width), and how would I do it? I'm new to rmarkdown.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by editing the CSS code:

```
<style>
  /* Set maximum width for content */
  body {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
</style>
```